# update database with change in list item spinner value

Tags: android

Hello I am very new in android, I am facing a problem, I am having a list view with item spinner, 
after changing all spinner in each row of listview, it should update values to database on submit button click, but it is changing last value only.

thanks in advance.

```
    slot1_spinn.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            value_spinn1 = slot1_spinn.getSelectedItem().toString();
            System.out.println("spinner on click value  "
                    + value_spinn1);

            int id = arg2;
            m_id = picture.member_id;

            System.out.println("slot1 spinner onclick get member id "
                    + m_id);


            System.out.println("spinner id "
                    + id);
            int spinnerValue = slot1_spinn.getSelectedItemPosition();
            System.out.println(slot1_spinn.getSelectedItemPosition());

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

this is list item spinner click listener

below is the code for update value

```
private void edit_attendance() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String date_update = datePicker.getText().toString();

        baseHandler = new DataBaseHandler(EditAttendance.this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = baseHandler.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();


        args.put("status", value_spinn1);
        args.put("slot1", value_spinn1);
        args.put("slot2", value_spinn1);

        String[] args11 = new String[] { date_update, m_id };
        db.update("attendance", args, "att_date=? AND member_id=?",
                args11);


        db.close();
        baseHandler.close();



        System.out.println("edit_attendance value_spinn1"
                + value_spinn1);

        System.out.println("edit_attendance date_update" + date_update);
        System.out.println("edit_attendance member id" + m_id);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Attendance has been changed successfully", 5000).show();

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that it because you are saving the value selected by the spinner like so:

```
        value_spinn1 = slot1_spinn.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Yet, in the update method you are saving the value of `m_id` not `value_spinn1`, `m_id` appears to always have the value taken from the picture object, as assigned in the Item Selected Listener:

```
        m_id = picture.member_id;
```

Assuming that the list of objects that are being bound to the spinner are the same class as `picture` it would be possible to get the member id by binding the spinner to a custom adapter that overrides `getItemId()`

```
public class PictureAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
List<Picture> pictures;

public PictureAdapter(Context context, List<picture> pictures) {
    this.context = context;
    this.pictures = pictures;
}

public int getCount()
{
    return pictures.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position)
{
    return members.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position)
{
     return pictures.get(position).member_id;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context); 
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_picture_layout); 
    }

    //Or however you store your images        ((ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.member_image)).setImageResource(getItem(position).imageResource));

return view;
}
```

}

And then in the Item Selected Listener, the final argument will be the member Id:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int postion, long id)  
{
    m_id = id;
}
```